# Return a random order of a list into a single cell

Tags: excel

I have a list: [a,b,c,d,e]

I want to return a random order of this list into an individual cell, 20 times. I have only been to use =Rand() to pull random integers for each value and sort multiple cells randomly.

In the end i want a random order of the list in an individual cell. I cant seem to figure it out:
|a,b,c,d,e|
|b,d,e,a,c|
|c,a,b,e,d|
...etc

Comment: Is this list in another cell, or in multiple cells?

Comment: Could be either. I imagine multiple cells would be easier to fit in a function.

Comment: do the 20 cells need to be unique? True random will sometimes cause duplication in the order.

Comment: Does not have to be unique. Should have specified that aspect.

Comment: just saw that this if for Excel 2010.  This will take vba in that version.  At least without an excessive amount of helper columns.

Answer (score 1):

In office 365 Excel put this in the first cell and copy down 20 rows:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,INDEX($A$1:$A$5,UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1000,1,1,5,TRUE))))
```

[image]

Older version we will need 5 helper columns.

In a column which is right of a blank column we put:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($1:$5)/(COUNTIF($B1:B1,$A$1:$A$5)=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,6-COLUMN(A1))))
```

Then copy that over 5 columns and down 20.

[image]

Then it is just a matter of concatenation:

```
=C1&","&D1&","&E1&","&F1&","&G1
```

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome breakdown. Thank you!!