# Five random items from a a list into a single cell separated by a comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have n number of unique values in n cells in Column A. (For ex: EDN12, EDN122, EDN991, ....)

I want to return any five unique values without repetition in a random order from Column A into an individual cell n times separated by a comma. For example; (EDN12, EDN112, EDN991, EDN881, EDN12)

How do I achieve this?

I have tried this formula provided here ([Return a random order of a list into a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68503343/return-a-random-order-of-a-list-into-a-single-cell/68503680#68503680) )

`=TEXTJOIN(",",,INDEX($A$1:$A$5,UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(1000,1,1,5,TRUE))))`

But it only generates five values for starting five cells in column A and rest are omitted.

Comment: check out "random" on here, then this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503680/4961700

Comment: Hello, I tried this however this method doesn't generate 5 values only. It fills the cells with n number of values. I only need 5 unique values without repetition.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for not mentioning that, I have edited for the information that i missed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the link shown has a theoretical chance of returning duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming values in column A are unique on their own, try:

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(A:A,3),TEXTJOIN(", ",,TAKE(SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(x))),5)))
```

Otherwise just nest 'x' in `UNIQUE()`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,3)),TEXTJOIN(", ",,TAKE(SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(x))),5)))
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works however the TOCOL function is only available for office 365. Is there any other way to do this without using this function.

Comment: Sure, use `FILTER()` instead. And you could swap `TAKE()` with `INDEX()`. For example: `=LET(x,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(SORTBY(x,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(x))),ROW($1:$5))))`

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate formula to get the required results without using LET.
Although I prefer the solution using the LET function.

```
=INDEX(A3:A22,INDEX(UNIQUE(RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A3:A22),1,1,COUNTA(A3:A22))),SEQUENCE(5)))
```

Breaking it down:

Get an array of random numbers based on the number of data rows.

```
=RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A3:A22),1,1,COUNTA(A3:A22),TRUE)
```

Extract the unique values from the array of random numbers.

```
=UNIQUE(C3#)
```

Extract the first five unique values

```
=INDEX(D3#,SEQUENCE(5))
```

Use the extracted values to extract matching rows from the source data.

```
=INDEX(A3:A22,E3#)
```

Finally join the values into a single cell.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,F3#)
```

[image]

If your list of data is very short, then it can return non-unique values.
Although your example appears to have at least 1000 data rows, so it will not be a problem.